# Convert a Word File to Test Questions C#

Tags: c#, ms-word

I have a Microsoft word file like this:

```
C1: 1 + 1 = ? 

    A. 0        B. 1         C. 2        D. 3
```

(show Paragraph Mark)

[image]

I want convert to:

[image: Img1]

```
C1: 1 + 1 = ?
A. 0    
B. 1   
C. 2    
D. 3
```

I was use:

```
string inputFileO = dialog.FileName;

Application wordApp = new Application();
Document wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(inputFileO);
Range rng = wordDoc.Range();

foreach (Range range in wordApp.ActiveDocument.StoryRanges)
{
range.Find.Text = "B.";
range.Find.Replacement.Text = "\rB.";
range.Find.Wrap = WdFindWrap.wdFindContinue;
object replaceAll = WdReplace.wdReplaceAll;
range.Find.Execute(Replace: ref replaceAll);
}
```

But not successful.

[image]

Update: I found that, number of paragraph in two time is only 3.

I Want to number of paragraph in second time is 5.

Update2: With this code from Frenchy (thanks a lot)

```
 public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

        Document wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open("d:\\+test.docx");

        string TextToReplace = string.Empty;

        //read all text in string
        foreach (Range tmpRange in wordDoc.StoryRanges)
            TextToReplace += tmpRange.Text;

        //replace in string
        var NewText = Regex.Replace(TextToReplace, @"\s*(?<answer>[ABCD]\. [0123])\s*", "${answer}\r", RegexOptions.Multiline);
        NewText = Regex.Replace(NewText, @"\?", "?\r", RegexOptions.Multiline);

        //replace in word and save
        wordDoc.Activate();
        FindAndReplace(wordApp, TextToReplace, NewText);

        wordDoc.Save();
        wordDoc.Close();
    }

    private void FindAndReplace(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application doc, object findText, object replaceWithText)
    {
        //options
        object matchCase = false;
        object matchWholeWord = true;
        object matchWildCards = false;
        object matchSoundsLike = false;
        object matchAllWordForms = false;
        object forward = true;
        object format = false;
        object matchKashida = false;
        object matchDiacritics = false;
        object matchAlefHamza = false;
        object matchControl = false;
        object read_only = false;
        object visible = true;
        object replace = 2;
        object wrap = 1;
        //execute find and replace
        doc.Selection.Find.Execute(ref findText, ref matchCase, ref matchWholeWord,
            ref matchWildCards, ref matchSoundsLike, ref matchAllWordForms, ref forward, ref wrap, ref format, ref replaceWithText, ref replace,
            ref matchKashida, ref matchDiacritics, ref matchAlefHamza, ref matchControl);
    }
}
```

i was successful

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the code i am using to modify some document Word, i have adapted to your problem:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

        Document wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open("d:\\+test.docx");

        string TextToReplace = string.Empty;

        //read all text in string
        foreach (Range tmpRange in wordDoc.StoryRanges)
            TextToReplace += tmpRange.Text;

        //replace in string
        var NewText = Regex.Replace(TextToReplace, @"\s*(?<answer>[ABCD]\. [0123])\s*", "${answer}\r", RegexOptions.Multiline);
        NewText = Regex.Replace(NewText, @"\?", "?\r", RegexOptions.Multiline);

        //replace in word and save
        wordDoc.Activate();
        FindAndReplace(wordApp, TextToReplace, NewText);

        wordDoc.Save();
        wordDoc.Close();
    }

    private void FindAndReplace(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application doc, object findText, object replaceWithText)
    {
        //options
        object matchCase = false;
        object matchWholeWord = true;
        object matchWildCards = false;
        object matchSoundsLike = false;
        object matchAllWordForms = false;
        object forward = true;
        object format = false;
        object matchKashida = false;
        object matchDiacritics = false;
        object matchAlefHamza = false;
        object matchControl = false;
        object read_only = false;
        object visible = true;
        object replace = 2;
        object wrap = 1;
        //execute find and replace
        doc.Selection.Find.Execute(ref findText, ref matchCase, ref matchWholeWord,
            ref matchWildCards, ref matchSoundsLike, ref matchAllWordForms, ref forward, ref wrap, ref format, ref replaceWithText, ref replace,
            ref matchKashida, ref matchDiacritics, ref matchAlefHamza, ref matchControl);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank for your help. But when i use with a long text, it say: : 'String parameter too long.'

Comment: sorry but i just answer to your original problem (just question about calculus) and  now you change the starting  hypotheses...its not the same problem and my answer dont answer to that. so. to avoid confusion, i suggest you to ask another problem with all hypotheses and let the original problem here..

Comment: i have the other solution but its completely different its the reason i ask you to open a new question and validate these to close the question

Comment: I am so sorry, i just want give an example fof my problem. Thank for your help!

Comment: if my answer help you, please validate and/or upvote to close the question..thanks

Comment: oh, sorry, how to vote and active? i just click votes?

Comment: yes you could vote on up arrow and validate with the check...dont forget to ask your new question if you havent solution